# How to schedule a task with a timer

Tags: kotlin

How can I schedule a task that checks if a value is true once every 2 seconds? I am doing this:

```
suspend fun a() {
   while(true) {
      if(isReady()) {
          break
      }
      delay(2000)
   }
   doWork()
}
```

I feel there should be a more idiomatic way to do this. I cannot change `isReady()` so a callback is not possible.

Would like to use coroutines. Also, `TimerTask` has given me issues in the past with different devices.

Comment: [`timer` - Creates a timer that executes the specified action periodically](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/timer.html)

Comment: But that uses a thread. I want to use coroutines.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? Looks fine to me. `isReady()` probably needs to be synchronized along with whatever makes it true.

Answer (score 0):

The more idiomatic way would be

```
while(!isReady()) {
    delay(2000)
}
doWork()
```

(or stick the `while` block on one line if you want, that's idiomatic too)

but otherwise that's pretty much the basic case for using coroutines, and it's the same way you'd run simple tasks on a thread too (sleep until a flag is set). Do you need something more complex?